# PUll to remoterepository using git extension

Tags: git

Git following error trying to pull.

> C:\program Files (x86)\git\bin\git.exe fetch -- progress "original"
>       fatal: protocol error: bed length character:git@

Did someone came across and is there any solution available?

Comment: Why don't you run this command in git bash instead?

Comment: `protocol error: bed length character` means that the remote side write something to stdout. Try to login to `origin` using `ssh` and see what it writes.